# What is the best way to loop through and process a large (10GB+) text file?

Tags: python, mysql, parsing, scripting, large-files

I need to loop through a very large text file, several gigabytes in size (a zone file to be exact). I need to run a few queries for each entry in the zone file, and then store the results in a searchable database.

My weapons of choice at the moment, mainly because I know them, are Python and MySQL. I'm not sure how well either will deal with files of this size, however.

Does anyone with experience in this area have any suggestions on the best way to open and loop through the file without overloading my system? How about the most efficient way to process the file once I can open it (threading?) and store the processed data?

Comment: Is the data is formatted one like JSON?

Comment: The zone file is formatted as specified in RFC 1035, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't have any real trouble storing that amount of data in MySQL, although you will probably not be able to store the entire database in memory, so expect some IO performance issues.  As always, make sure you have the appropriate indices before running your queries.

The most important thing is to not try to load the entire file into memory.  Loop through the file, don't try to use a method like readlines which will load the whole file at once.

Make sure to batch the requests. Load up a few thousand lines at a time and send them all in one big SQL request.

This approach should work:

```
def push_batch(batch):
    # Send a big INSERT request to MySQL

current_batch = []
with open('filename') as f:
    for line in f:
        batch.append(line)

        if len(current_batch) > 1000:
            push_batch(current_batch)
            current_batch = []

    push_batch(current_batch)
```

Zone files are pretty normally formatted, consider if you can get away with just using [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).  You might also consider creating a named pipe, pushing partially formatted data in to it from python, and using LOAD DATA INFILE to read it in with MySQL.

MySQL has some great tips on [optimizing inserts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html), some highlights:

- Use multiple value lists in each insert statement.
- Use INSERT DELAYED, particularly if you are pushing from multiple clients at once (e.g. using threading).
- Lock your tables before inserting.
- Tweak the key_buffer_size and bulk_insert_buffer_size.

The fastest processing will be done in MySQL, so consider if you can get away with doing the queries you need after the data is in the db, not before.  If you do need to do operations in Python, threading is not going to help you.  Only one thread of Python code can execute at a time (GIL), so unless you're doing something which spends a considerable amount of time in C, or interfaces with external resources, you're only going to ever be running in one thread anyway.

The most important optimization question is *what is bounding the speed*, there's no point spinning up a bunch of threads to read the file, if the database is the bounding factor.  The only way to really know is to try it and make tweaks until it is fast enough for your purpose.

Comment: Some really valuable information here Zack, thanks! After I get the data parsed and stored, I'm going to be running a list of regular expressions on each entry and executing a few network requests (ping, etc). I'm going to do this in a separate script, and I'm not sure if Python would be most optimal for this - I was told C++ would be better.

Comment: @MarathonStudios Python would be fine, as the bulk of the time spent during operations like ping are waiting for the network requests.  That would be a time when using multiple threads would be very valuable.  Create a `threading.Queue` of zones to be tested, a pool of threads that pull an entry off the queue, test it and store the results, and one or more threads that query the db for a few dozen as-yet untested entries and add them to the queue.  Tweak the number of loading and consuming threads to optimize the performance.

Comment: @MarathonStudios Regular expressions would be fine as well, as the actual implementation in the re module is in C anyway.  Make sure you compile the expressions first (http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.compile), so it doesn't have to be redone for each entry.  Note however that MySQL does support regular expressions (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), and anything done in the DB is generally going to be faster than an external program (use UPDATE statements).

Answer (score 0):

@Zack Bloom's answer is excellent and I upvoted it.  Just a couple of thoughts:

- As he showed, just using `with open(filename) as f:` / `for line in f` is all you need to do.  `open()` returns an iterator that gives you one line at a time from the file.
- If you want to slurp every line into your database, do it in the loop.  If you only want certain lines that match a certain regular expression, that's easy.

```
    import re

    pat = re.compile(some_pattern)

    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if not pat.search(line):
                continue
            # do the work to insert the line here
```

- With a file that is multiple gigabytes, you are likely to be I/O bound.  So there is likely no reason to worry about multithreading or whatever.  Even running several regular expressions is likely to crunch through the data faster than the file can be read or the database updated.
- Personally, I'm not much of a database guy and I like using an ORM.  The last project I did database work on, I was using Autumn with SQLite.  I found that the default for the ORM was to do one commit per insert, and it took forever to insert a bunch of records, so I extended Autumn to let you explicitly bracket a bunch of inserts with a single commit; it was *much* faster that way.  (Hmm, I should extend Autumn to work with a Python `with` statement, so that you could wrap a bunch of inserts into a `with` block and Autumn would automatically commit.)

http://autumn-orm.org/

Anyway, my point was just that with database stuff, doing things the wrong way can be very slow.  If you are finding that the database inserting is your bottleneck, there might be something you can do to fix it, and Zack Bloom's answer contains several ideas to start you out.